# jquery Masonry - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong with my jQuery masonry code. I've posted the link to my test page below:

http://davidlloydphotography.com/home.html

I have followed the step by step guide the Masonry website (http://masonry.desandro.com/). I think it might be how I'm initialising the jQuery, not sure where it goes, the tutorial is not clear:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 700
});
```

No idea why it won't flow into the layout, the placeholder images just hang to the left :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been at this for days, its got to be a simple problem.

Comment: For starters, you are not even initialising Masonry! Either change $('.grid') to $('#grid') or in your HTML change <div id="grid"> to <div class="grid">

Answer (score 2):

You should use only one version of jQuery, (not 2 depending on the browser) and put your js at the bottom of the page and load masonry with "document ready".
If you are loading many images, consider using [imagesloaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com) as well.

HTML:

```
 <div id="grid">
 <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="" />
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>  

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#grid').masonry({
 // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
 columnWidth: 700
});
});
</script>
```